# How to retrieve & share bitmap from device folder

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream, outputstream

I am building a meme generator app.  So far, the app does everything I need it to do but I want to add 1 more functionality.  The app saves the meme as a `bitmap` on my device.  I want to add a functionality where, if the user wishes to share the meme on Facebook, Twitter, IG, etc, the app retrieves that same bitmap (which was just created.).

I'm not worried about the sharing function at the moment.  I want to find out how I can retrieve the file to be able to share it.

This is the method where the creation and saving of the meme takes place.  I will omit unnecessary code:

```
public void createBitmapAndSave(ImageView img) {

        ...

        counter++;

        File file;
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
        file = new File(path + "/SimpliMeme/" + timeStamp + "-" + counter + ".jpg");
        file.getParentFile().mkdir();

        try {
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Top Text: " + String.valueOf(topTextMeasurement) + " and bottom text: " + String.valueOf(bottomTextMeasurement),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

and I've created an empty method that needs to be called when the user hits the "Share" button:

```
public void shareMeme(){}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out how can you get the saved image from your device?

Comment: Yes but the specific image that was just created and saved.

Comment: As I can see the code, every time you are saving the image in the folder it's having a different name. Do you want to save each image differently or you can just overwrite the preovious one with the same name.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  I am giving *each image* a different name.  Not "the image".  Each time creates a new meme or hits the save button twice for the same one, the app creates new names for each.

Comment: If you want to fetch the latest image out of the saved images then you should name the image with timestamp so that you can convert it and compare the datetime object.

Comment: I think its better to divide this in 2 different processes.  Because the user can click on "Share" before "Save" or might not click "Save" at all and just wants to share it directly from the app.  In the case of just sharing, it makes sense for the app to create the bitmap (specifically for sharing), show the dialog to choose where to share it and export the bitmap there (and not save it to the device).  This, imo, is a cleaner approach than going back to the device to scavenge for stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you've mentioned earlier, you gotta divide this big method into 2 small ones.

As far as your initial question goes:  There is no point in going back to your device just to find and get that same photo.  Divide the method into 2 methods (`createBitmap()` & `saveBitmap()`, for example) and if the user just wants to share it without saving it to the device, the app will just call the `createBitmap()` method to only create the bitmap and then you'll use that in your upcoming sharing functionality.